# Sign TX with metamask and generate TxHash before sending to node

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I am creating an ERC20 payment for my website. It consists of:

1. filling out a form.
2. sending TxHash +form to backend to store in database.
3. Listening to "transfer" method on the ERC20 contract.
4. when receiving the hash, payment is checked and confirmed.

In my current flow the transaction has to be submitted to a node to receive the transaction hash which i then send along with the form data to my backend.

I would like to be able to send to TxHash and the form at the same time (before the Tx is submitted to the node). The reason being, id like to avoid a situation where the transaction is mined but the api call to submit the form + TxHash failed. This would mean the user would pay but there is no record of the submitted form or transaction.

basically i would like the TxHash and form data save in my database before submitting the transaction to a node.

I need to sign the transaction with Metamask, receive the signed transaction back so i can calculate the transaction hash. Then actually submit the signed transaction through Metamask. I cannot work out how to achieve this with Ethers.

I would like to avoid creating the transaction myself as i would like Metamask to recommend gas (Although i don't believe what i want is possible and will have to do this anyway).

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const ABI = getAbi();
const MyContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, provider);

const contractWithSigner = MyContract.connect(signer);
const token = ethers.utils.parseUnits("6.0", 18);

const tx = await contractWithSigner.transfer(account2, token);
```